# undefined Message on Console When priting JSON object Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, json

I have created a JSON object, Now when i am trying to print the data from JSON object, I am getting no output on `document.write` and `undefined` Message on Console.

Kindly check my code and guide me where i am making the Mistake.

```
<head>

<script>

    var variable= 
    [
        {
            "first_name": "Steve",
            "last_name": "Jobs",
            "Education" :   [
                                {"Intermediate" :   "2006"  },
                                {"Bachelors"    :   "2009"  },
                                {"Masters"      :   "2015"  }           
                            ]

        },


        {
            "first_name": "Bill",
            "last_name": "Gates",
            "Education": [
                        {"Intermediate"     :   "2010"},
                        {"Bachelors"        :   "2012"},
                        {"Masters"          :   "2014"}

            ]

            }


    ];



console.log(variable.first_name);

for (key in variable.Education)
{
    console.log(key);

    }

</script>

</head>
```

Comment: `console.log(variable[0].first_name);`

Comment: @SridharR is correct. What you have here isn't just an object, it's an array with an object in it. So you have to access the array to get to the object.

Comment: Thanks its working..But how can i do this in for loop? Its giving me output on `Console.log` and `document.write`...But on loop its not displaying anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your "variable" is an array so yon can't show a proprety of an element until define correctly where is the proprety.

as :

```
console.log(variable[0].Education)
```

or doing a loop :

```
for (var i = 0; i <variable.length; i++){
   console.log(variable[i].Education);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Its working great..How can i use this `foreach` loop of Javascript.

Comment: no foreach in javascript you can use `for (var key in variable) { console.log(variable[key].Education); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
for (var i in variable) {
    var k = variable[i].Education;
    console.log(Object.keys(variable[i])) // displays all keys
    for (var j in k)
    console.log(Object.keys(k[j])) // displays Education keys
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LAH6L/2/)